# Is there a term for using Google or other search engines to cheat at trivia?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a most meta act, I've been trying to search for such a term, but as you may have guessed, it's extremely difficult to get meaningful results when including the words in my question. Lots of noise, no obvious signal. So, does such a term even exist for using search engines to cheat and find the answer to trivia or brain teaser type questions?

My goal is to use the term in a trivia question, e.g. "What does '_____' mean?" so that the person I suspect of cheating can embarrass themselves. ;)

Comment: I voted this down because of the assumption it makes, that we need a specific word that means "to cheat at trivia games by doing an online search".  What we need are Quizzo proctors with tasers.

Comment: I don't see how that's necessarily a dealbreaker. I can remove my opinion, since the essence of the question is does such a term exist. You should approve, since my goal is to use the term in a trivia question, e.g. "What does '_____' mean?" so that the person I suspect of cheating can embarrass themselves. ;)

Comment: How about Russell Brand’s brand of cheating at the 10th anniversary Big Fat Quiz a few weeks ago? Does that count? (Some people in the audience were texting him answers that were, if not actually all that good, then at least more accurate than what he'd come up with himself. Until Jimmy Carr confiscated the phone, that is.)

Comment: "Being a douchenozzle" maybe? If you call them that when they are googling the answer, they'll understand.

Answer (score 6):

There almost certainly is not, nor is there a need for one; the commonly used 'googling' would be perfectly clear if used in context. eg. "Jim kept googling answers at trivia last night."

Also worth noting: Coining new neologisms is out of scope for EL&U.

Comment: Isn't weather a word is needed or not irrelevant? In almost any situation one can use a discription or idiom but one may prefer to find out if one concise word exists.

Comment: @Gitty Sure...so one almost certainly does not exist. The question posed by OP ended by stating that if none existed then we should come up with one. I think it's perfectly reasonable to argue that a new word isn't needed when it is proposed that we contrive a silly neologism with narrow applicability.

Comment: @DaveMagner I am in no way suggesting this site coin a word. I've removed that last sentence to prevent additional confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I am part of an English-speaking community that engages in serious competitive quizzing. Most of the quizzing is done in-person, but occasionally, more casual quizzes are conducted online (for convenience's sake), via Skype or instant messaging, and in uncontrolled environments (i.e. the participants connect from their home computers and aren't overseen by proctors or anything), and so this of course entails a risk that the participants will Google for answers as they participate. Indeed, this has happened to us more than once.

Despite this, we do not have a term for this behavior; when we do want to refer to it by some shorthand, we usually use some locution involving the name of the perpetrator of the most notorious cheating-by-Googling incident, e.g. "pulling a Fred" (except that the name of the perpetrator is not Fred).

All of this is to say - Dave Magner's answer is correct; there is no term for this. But hey, if you want, check back with me in a decade or so - I suspect by then there'll have been enough instances of this that we'll have coined a term for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have to come up with a term for that.  Technology has evolved quite rapidly, even faster than the English language, it seems.  I was recently at a table quiz and we were told no 'artificial intelligence or expert systems' were allowed. Does this help?